# FTP: 500 unknow command

Tags: c++, tcp, ftp

i try to do basic ftp client and I have got problem. I succesfully send user and password with correct response, bud then if I want to send others command, it send me back "500 unknown command" everytime.. 
What can I do wrong?

Code:

```
string message = "PWD"; 
message.append("\n"); 
cout << message; 
if((send(mysocket,message.c_str(),message.size() + 1, 0 )) < 0){ 
    cerr << "Error" << endl;
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Check the traffic with wirehark

Comment: I checked it, but cant find problem.. there is screen from wireshark http://postimg.org/image/uwu9jfsot/

Comment: Hm, no idea until now. Server is ok too. Can you show more code, maybe even a compilable thing?

Answer (score 0):

There is no PWD command in FTP, its called CWD. See RFC959 for the FTP commands.

Comment: I use these commands [link](http://www.pda-archives.com/dmbrowne/ftpclient.htm) but noone work :-/ with CWD it is same..

Comment: You might try to use \r\n instead of \n. Per RFC \r\n is the correct line end and some servers might like to enforce this. If this does not help please provide a pcap (e.g. not only a picture of wireshark) to see what is really going on.